# Can range-v3 contains work on initializer list?

Tags: c++, c++20, range-v3

I am quite happy that range-v3 finally adds a contains algorithm.
But I would like if I would not have to produce a container for it to work. 
Consider this example:

```
#include <range/v3/algorithm/contains.hpp>
enum class Status{
    OK, 
    TimedOut,
    TryAgain,
    PermanentFailure
};

bool f(Status s){
    std::array can_retry{Status::OK, Status::TimedOut};
    return ranges::contains(can_retry,s);
}
int main(){
    return f(Status::TryAgain);
}
```

Here I would like to inline `{Status::OK, Status::TimedOut}` into call to contains, but it fails.
Is there any way to do this?

P.S. please no comments about maintainability/readability of code I want, it is just an example code. :)

Comment: You could file an issue asking them to add a default template parameter, so this code would just work.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to inline your two-line snippet into one like so:

```cpp
return ranges::contains(std::array{Status::Ok, Status::TimedOut}, s);
```